# Time-based WFR or Trigger?

Tags: workflow, formula, time-dependent-workflow

I'm looking to create a follow-up Task record if a Case has been in certain status for a certain period of time.

Essentially like this:

(Picklist) **Case Status**: `X`

(Date) **Case Status Update** : `01/01/2019`

When 7 days have passed since `X` status was applied and the status remains the same today, create follow-up Task for Case owner.

With workflow rules I don't think it's possible, as there is no other updates being done either during the 7 day wait period or after. The next Status update can come at any time.

Is the only option really to have a daily apex batchjob running and checking the Case Status and calculating the days difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [time-based workflow rule](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000005245&type=1) or [process builder](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=process_limits_scheduled_processing.htm&type=5) for this purpose. The criteria would be "when the status is X" on "when a record is created or subsequently edited to meet the criteria." The time delay would be for "seven days after the rule trigger date." How both time-based workflow rules and process builder flows work is that they place a "reminder" in the appropriate queue and execute the actions when the timer expires, *if* the criteria is still met. If the record is modified before the task is created in a way that "status is not X", then the reminder is removed from the queue and no task will be created.

Comment: Thanks for the quick help on this! So basically if Case is updated to status X in 2 days after creation for an example, the WFR can check the custom Case Status Update field and fire the action 7 days after it was changed to Status X? (IF it still is in status X at that time)

Comment: @Rain Correct. That's how it works. You'll probably want to read the documentation, too, it goes in to more detail.